# Сменить корень сайта через .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Дорабатываю существующую CMS, и теперь встала задача локализовать сайт (Америка и Канада), собственно любой урл для Америки будет иметь вид (относительно корня) `/about-us/`, а для Канады - `/ca/about-us/`, т.е. все те же урлы, только с префиксом `/ca/`. Сначала была идея пропускать все относительные ссылки через функцию, которая и будет добавлять этот префикс, но минусом этого подхода есть то, что слишком много работы придется сделать, что-бы переписать все урлы во всех шаблонах (и в некоторых `.js` файлах).

Собственно, интересует возможность смены КОРНЯ сайта, в зависимости от входящего урла, что-бы все относительные ссылки теперь были с корректным префиксом.

Сейчас вся входящая логика реализована на одном правиле:

`RewriteRule ^(ca)(?:/([A-Za-z0-9-/]+)?)?$ /$2?localization=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`

Собственно, может есть какой-то `RewriteCond`, что-бы реализовал такую логику, или же иной подход?

Comment: так что вы имеете ввиду под корнем директорию с файлами на сервере или что то другое.

Comment: @Naumov Хм, даже не знаю. То место, откуда все относительные ссылки начинаются.